# Batch script to find System make and model then run another script

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a batch script to find out a computers manufacture, model and then execute another batch script that I have already created.

So far I have this to get the Computer Manufacturer:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic ComputerSystem Get Manufacturer /value') do SET manufacturer=%%A
```

and this to get the model:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic ComputerSystem Get Model /value') do SET model=%%A
```

Now I'm not sure how to use the make and models as variables within an IF statement.

Comment: does this work for you?: `if "%manufacturer%" == "Hewlett-Packard" echo yes`

Answer (score 1):

The first issue: how-to assign `wmic` output to an environment variable:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic computersystem get model /value'
  ) do for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%~b") do set "model=%%c"
echo %model%
```

Where the for loops are

- `%%a` to retrieve the model (in the second token, `%%b`)
- `%%c` to remove the ending carriage return in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`)

Another *potential* issue: how-to *reference* an environment variable, if assigned within a command block `(`in parentheses`)`:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "model=nothing assigned yet"
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic computersystem get model /value'
  ) do for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%~b") do (
      set "model=%%c"
      echo %model% :referenced using percent signs within a command block
      SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
         echo !model!  :referenced using exclamation marks within a command block
      ENDLOCAL
    )
echo %model%  :referenced using percent signs out of a command block
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Run above script to see [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) effect:

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\29893432.bat
nothing assigned yet :referenced using percent signs within a command block
System Product Name  :referenced using exclamation marks within a command block
System Product Name  :referenced using percent signs out of a command block

==>
```

Follow Stephan's comment on using [`If` statement](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).